# How to compute the sorted connected components of a graph efficiently?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

The code below computes the connected components of the undirected graph and sorts them according to the directed graph. It is possible since by (the real) definition of `edges`, the subgraph generated by any connected component will **always** be a path graph. Or said differently, the undirected graph is a disjoint union of path graphs.

```
edges = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujaNL.png"],"Byte"]]]]

sortedComps = With[{dirGraph = DirectedEdge @@@ edges,
 comps = ConnectedComponents[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges]},
      FindHamiltonianPath[Subgraph[dirGraph, #]] & /@ comps];
```

The evaluation is horribly slow. How to compute `sortedComps` more efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you after, if no, you can tell me

```
TopologicalSort /@ WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents[DirectedEdge @@@ edges]
```